# Find only text inside BeautifulSoup element

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I run this python BS code:

```
soup=BeautifulSoup(wd.page_source, 'lxml')
price_divs = soup.find_all("div", class_="flt-subhead1 gws-flights-results__price gws-flights-results__cheapest-price")
print(price_divs)
```

This output:

```html
<div class="flt-subhead1 gws-flights-results__price gws-flights-results__cheapest-price">
  <span class="gws-flights-results__carry-on-definitely-not-included gws-flights-results__marker" jsaction="LoTHjf;mouseenter:LoTHjf;mouseleave:QsRKXb" role="button" tabindex="-1"></span> €105</div>
<div class="flt-subhead1 gws-flights-results__price gws-flights-results__cheapest-price">
  <span class="gws-flights-results__carry-on-definitely-not-included gws-flights-results__marker" jsaction="LoTHjf;mouseenter:LoTHjf;mouseleave:QsRKXb" role="button" tabindex="-1"></span> €105</div>
<div class="flt-subhead1 gws-flights-results__price gws-flights-results__cheapest-price">€107</div>
<div class="flt-subhead1 gws-flights-results__price gws-flights-results__cheapest-price"> €107</div>
```

I want this just to give me an array of all prices something like:

```
[105,107]
```

Thanks

Comment: Post a sample of you `lxml` or `wd.page_source`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without having a sample of your file, try:

```
soup=BeautifulSoup(wd.page_source, 'lxml')
price_divs = soup.find_all("div", class_="flt-subhead1 gws-flights-results__price gws-flights-results__cheapest-price")

for price in price_divs:
    print(price.text)
```

Why:

Iterate through the divs in order to find each one's text only.

Comment: __Tip:__ For other onlookers to this question, always look for unique non-dynamic attributes same to the tags you need.